# TYPO3 selectSingle, add an option which creates a new element (addRecord)

Tags: typo3, element, record, typo3-9.x

I have a selectSingle element which gets a list of some addresses from another table. Since the following doesn't work on TYPO3 v9 with selectSingle

```
'fieldControl' => [
   'editPopup' => [
        'disabled' => false,
    ],
    'addRecord' => [
        'disabled' => false,
    ],
    'listModule' => [
        'disabled' => false,
    ],
],
```

i would like to create an option inside the select list which duplicates the behaviour of the `addRecord`. So far my elements is located in

**myExt/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_domain_model_modelName**

and my element looks like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['columns']['db_field'] = [
    'exclude' => false,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:.db_field',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => [
            ["LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:.selectItem", 0],
        ],
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_ext_domain_model_address',
    ],
];
```

If there is a way around it (`addRecord`) i would definetely use it. If not, i would really appreciate it of you point me to the right direction on how to create this item inside the select list.

**Additional information**

i tried to use the following code [Code](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/81976#note-4)  but i got this error:

> Too few arguments to function
>   TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\Element\AbstractFormElement::__construct(), 0
>   passed in
>   /my/home/path/htdocs/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
>   on line 3667 and exactly 2 expected

and the function which causes this error inside the ***AbstractFormElement::__construct*** looks like this:

```
public function __construct(NodeFactory $nodeFactory, array $data)
    {
        parent::__construct($nodeFactory, $data);
        $this->iconFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(IconFactory::class);
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you considered `group` instead and setting its `size` and `maxitems` accordingly? In `group` the mentioned `fieldControl` options are available.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala is there a way to get the list of the db records? Because now i will have to click on the folder button in order to get a record from the folder that they are created

Comment: No, that's not possible with `group`. Usually that's also a good thing since it prevents loading a huge list of records at once. Also you can use the suggest wizard to quickly look for records.